# Console.setwindowsize не работает на macos

Tags: c#, консоль

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.SetWindowSize(500, 500);
    int y = 600;
    Console.Write("{0,2} {1,8} {2,16} {3,24} {4,32}","x","f1(x)","e = 10^2", "e = 10^3","e = 10^4");
    //double x = -0.6;
    //Func(x);
    //SecondFunc(x);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В [документации](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.console.setwindowsize?view=netframework-4.8) сказано, что `Console.SetWindowSize` работает только на Windows. Аналогичный [вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53894813/how-to-use-console-setwindowsize-on-linux-using-net-core) про Linux.